# How do I get a result from this mocked service?

Tags: c#, .net-core

How do I get a result from a mocked service? Note: It works properly. I'm just trying to get the test going.

The service:

```
    public interface ISendgridService
{
    Task<Response> SendAsync(IEmailMessage emailMessage);
}
```

// The test

```
        [TestMethod]
    public async Task SendEmailTest()
    {
        // Arrange
        var mockSendgrid = new Mock<ISendgridService>();

        var response = new Mock<Func<SendGrid.Response>>();

        mockSendgrid.Setup(s => s.SendAsync(It.IsAny<IEmailMessage>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(response.Object.Invoke);

        var emailMessage = _builder.CreateNew<EmailMessage>()
            .With(e => e.From = _sendgridConfiguration.SenderEmail)
            .With(e => e.FromName = _sendgridConfiguration.SenderName)
            .With(e => e.To = Faker.Internet.Email())
            .Build();


        // Act
        var result = await mockSendgrid.Object.SendAsync(emailMessage);

        // Assert
     // result is null // How do I get a value?
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to test here?

Comment: @Scott-hannen 's answer put me in the right direction. I was not providing a response to the mock. This was not possible with the SenGrid.Response class. I get this error with NBuilder. FizzWare.NBuilder.TypeCreationException: Response does not have a default parameterless constructor. I thought SendGrid.Response was inherited from a .Net class but it's not. I also didn't mean to propagate an external class into my application -- it affects my app when they change something. I want to handle it at the service layer. My solution was to create a ServiceResponse class and I can mock that.

Answer (score 3):

I am a little confused as to what you're trying to test. Usually, you'd act on a concrete class under test, not a stubbed object.

Pseudo code below:

```
public class SendGridService : ISendGridService {
  public async Task<bool> SendAsync() {
    //code that sends the email
  }
}
```

Your test would be like:

```
//Act
var subject = new SendGridService();
var result = await subject.SendAsync();

//Assert
Assert.IsTrue(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You've set up the `Mock<ISendgridService>` to return something - it uses another mock - `Mock<Func<SendGrid.Response>>` and returns the result of invoking that `Func`.

But you haven't set up the `Mock<Func<SendGrid.Response>>` to return anything, so it doesn't.

In other words, when you do this:

```
mockSendgrid.Setup(s => s.SendAsync(It.IsAny<IEmailMessage>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(response.Object.Invoke);
```

What does `response.Object.Invoke` return? `response.Object` is a `Mock<Func<SendGrid.Response>>`, but it hasn't been set up to return anything.

A `Func` is actually much easier to mock without using Moq. You can just do this:

```
// Create the thing you need the function to return, whatever that looks like.
var response = new SendGrid.Response(someStatusCode, body, headers); 

// create a function that returns it.
var functionMock = new Func<SendGrid.Response>(() => response);
```

Comment: I haven't found a way to instantiate ResponseHeaders. I get the error:  Cannot build an abstract class

Comment: Thanks. Your answer put me in the right direction. I was not providing a response to the mock. This was not possible with the SenGrid.Response class. I get this error with NBuilder. FizzWare.NBuilder.TypeCreationException: Response does not have a default parameterless constructor. I thought SendGrid.Response was inherited from a .Net class but it's not. I also didn't mean to propagate an external class into my application -- it affects my app when they change something. I want to handle it at the service layer. My solution was to create a ServiceResponse class and I can mock that.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you want to test of the app, if you are trying to test whether it sends an email or not, you shouldnt  be using a mock class if you want to actually test if it sends. What you should mock is the content of the email.

Now if what you want to check is that certain steps including the email works (integrating all of them in a method) thats another matter, in this case you should use a dummy task that returns a dummy response.